# How to find the output of a nested loop with a break

Tags: python, loops, break

I have to figure out what the output is, I know what the answer is but I just have no idea how they got that answer. If someone could do a step by step explanation that would be great.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
result = 0
while a < b:
    result = a * 2
    print(result)
    if result > c:
        break
    a += 4
```

Comment: The program prints something during the loop and the loop terminates with a result saved in a variable. Which of those is what you're calling "output"?

Comment: I fixed it I think.